# Flutter horizontal ListView BoxConstraints forces an infinite width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

currently I try to show a horizontal ListView Builder within a Card.
But I always get an error saying "**BoxConstraints forces an infinite width**."

If I build a List View with a vertical List everything works fine.
As soon as I change to a horizontal list the list disappears.

I will attach a Screenshoot where I mark the area in which the horizontal List View should be.
[Screnshoot of the current View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P08W6.png)

This is my last attempt for the second card:
(I removed the code for the first card so the code isn't too long)

```
Expanded(
child: Container(
height: 250.0,
child: Card(
color: Color(_colors.getBackgroundColor()),
elevation: 10.0,
shadowColor: Colors.black54,
margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
side: BorderSide(
color: Color(_colors.getLightMainColor()))),
     child: Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 250.0,
               child: ListView.builder(
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               itemCount: 1,
               itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return ListTile(
               title: Text('Test'),
                  );
                 }),
               )),
              ),
             ),
   ),
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the "Hello" at the beginning :)

Comment: Firstly, remove the `Expanded` widget and provide `width: double.infinity` to the `Container` and then explain clearly what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @HardikKumar thanks for your help. Sorry if my goal was not clear. I updated my post and added a screenshot. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated your code so that it could run properly.

**Remember, you can't have horizontal `ListTile`**

And let me know if you want something else

```
Container(
  height: 250.0,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Card(
    color: Colors.red,
    elevation: 10.0,
    shadowColor: Colors.black54,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      side: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: 250.0,
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 250.0,
              child: Text('Test')
            );
          }
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

It may help you

Comment: @HaridkKumar thanks!!! I did not know a list tile within a horizontal Listview isn't allow. 
Immense help! Thanks!